# PLSQL date variable then run in select

Tags: plsql

How do I use my date variable in select statement? Do I have to use INTO? Why can't I just declare variable then run select statement with variable in it?

Here is my code so far, I'm getting error table or view does not exist. Please show me how to correct this and also a more simple way to  declare variable then run select statement.

```
DECLARE
    mySysDate DATE := TO_DATE('1-MAY-2016');
    wtf varchar(512);

BEGIN

    select
        CASE
            WHEN to_char(mySysDate, 'mm') BETWEEN 08 AND 12 THEN to_char(add_months(mySysDate, 12), 'YYYY') || '10'
            WHEN to_char(mySysDate, 'mm') BETWEEN 01 AND 05 THEN to_char(mySysDate, 'YYYY') || '20'
            WHEN to_char(mySysDate, 'mm') BETWEEN 06 AND 07 THEN to_char(mySysDate, 'YYYY') || '30'
            ELSE 'X'
        END AS CurrentTerm
    into wtf
    from dual;

END;

select * from wtf;
```

Comment: fyi, `TO_DATE('1-MAY-2016')` should be `date '2016-05-01`. There is not much point using `to_date()` if you don't specify a format mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only select from a table or view, not a variable.  There is no table or view in your schema called `wtf`, hence the error.  To see the contents of variable `wtf`, use this instead of `'select * from wtf;'`

```
 dbms_output.put_line(wtf);
```

and move it inside of the `'END'` of the anonymous block.

I get `'201620'` by the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Gary_W is correct, but changing your select statement to this is a better solution.  There isn't much need to select from dual here, a simple assignment statement works fine.  Extract should also perform better and more logically than a to_char.

```
wtf := CASE
        WHEN extract(month from mySysDate) BETWEEN 08 AND 12 THEN to_char(add_months(mySysDate, 12), 'YYYY') || '10'
        WHEN extract(month from mySysDate) BETWEEN 01 AND 05 THEN to_char(mySysDate, 'YYYY') || '20'
        WHEN extract(month from mySysDate) BETWEEN 06 AND 07 THEN to_char(mySysDate, 'YYYY') || '30'
        ELSE 'X'
       END;
```